# How to use _popen() to both read and write to and from cmd in c (windows)?

Tags: c, windows

I have trouble understanding the _popen() function in c. When doing this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *cmd;
    cmd = _popen("whoami", "r");
    if(cmd == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR!");
        return 1;
    }
    char buffer[256];
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), cmd);
    printf("Output: %s", buffer);
    _pclose(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the desired output. When doing it that way however,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *cmd;
    cmd = _popen("cmd /K", "rw");
    if(cmd == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR!");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(cmd, "whoami\n");
    char buffer[256];
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), cmd);
    printf("Output: %s", buffer);
    _pclose(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

I just get an error. I read somewhere that _popen() doesn't support both reading and writing at the same time, but i have no clue on how to make it so i can open "a new console" and read from it and write to it at the same time. What would be an effective way to do so?

Comment: Pipes are one-direction only. You can use [`_popen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=msvc-170) to "open" command to either read or write, but not both. If you need to both read and write you might need to go to a lower level, perhaps to the Windows API [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) function.

Comment: you need to use [named pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipes) for bidirectional pipes